# sorting the list in Python without .sorted()

Tags: python, list

I have a list `a = ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2',]`

How can I get list `b = ['a1,', 'a2', 'b1', 'b2', 'c1', 'c2', 'd1', 'd2']` without using `.sorted()`?

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want to use sorted() then sort it yourself. :)

Comment: And why would you not want to use sorted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l = ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2']
numbersPerLetter = 2
lsorted = []
for i in range(len(l) / numbersPerLetter):
   lsorted.extend([l[x+i] for x in range(0, len(l), len(l) / numbersPerLetter)])
print(lsorted)
```

Output:

```
['a1', 'a2', 'b1', 'b2', 'c1', 'c2', 'd1', 'd2']
```

In Python 3.X you have to change `/` to `//` in order to make it work.

Comment: Could you please explain the loop inside the first loop?

Comment: It is called a list comprehension. More here: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions. For each iteration it creates a little list with the same letters. I mean indexes 0,4 next 1,5 next 2,6 and finally 3,7. More on range with 3 arguments here: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range

Comment: what the…? how can one make python look so ugly?

Comment: at the very least you could replace that list comprehension with a simple slice (i think… very hard to read your code): `lsorted.extend(l[i::len(l)/numbersPerLetter])`

Comment: @hop: By the way, I've just noticed that your answer is not really answer to the question. Funny.

Comment: @Maciej: how do you mean? except for the fact that the question is not really answerable…

Answer (score 5):

There is no `.sorted()` method for lists, though there is the `sorted()` function, as S.Mark pointed out (which returns a new sorted list), and a `.sort()` method (which sorts a list in place and returns `None`). If you meant to not use the `sorted()` function, then:

```
a = ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2',]
a.sort()
b = a
```

otherwise, maybe you can clarify your question further.

Comment: Okey. But if I have a list of playing card, then .sorted() doesn't work correctly!

Comment: There's no playing cards in the question, but you can use the optional argument 'key' to specify the sorting order.

Comment: @Bob, I don't understand what you're looking for. Are you looking for a way to sort things that are not letters or numbers? A way to sort strings by their meaning rather than their alphabetic order?

Answer (score 3):

It seems a bit arbitrary, not to use `sorted()`. I think you mean, that you don't want to sort the list in the (default) alphanumerical order.

Here is how you define a key for sorting strings that represent playing cards (a1 through d13) by suit, then rank:

```
>>> def cardsortkey(card):
...     return (card[0], int(card[1:]))
... 
>>> cardsortkey('a1')
('a', 1)
>>> a = ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1',
...      'a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2',
...      'a11', 'b11', 'c11', 'd11']
>>> sorted(a, key=cardsortkey)
['a1', 'a2', 'a11', 'b1', 'b2', 'b11', 'c1', 'c2', 'c11', 'd1', 'd2', 'd11']
```

Is that what you need?

Comment: +1. I agree, your answers is much more Pythonic and much more elegant. But I don't think that it is more obvious for noob python coder.

Answer (score 2):

without using sorted, but expensive way.

```
a = ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2',]
```

split it to 2 parts

```
['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1',] ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2',]
```

zip it

```
[('a1', 'a2'), ('b1', 'b2'), ('c1', 'c2'), ('d1', 'd2')]
```

and flatten it (with itertools here)

```
import itertools
itertools.chain(*zip(a[:len(a)/2],a[len(a)/2:]))
```

itertools returns iterator, so If you need list, wrapped it with list(), and assigned it to b

```
b = list(itertools.chain(*zip(a[:len(a)/2],a[len(a)/2:])))
=> ['a1', 'a2', 'b1', 'b2', 'c1', 'c2', 'd1', 'd2']
```

Answer (score 1):

just `b = sorted(a)` ?

Comment: **note**: original question does not say not to use `sorted()`, so posted this, but I have no idea now.

Answer (score 0):

You can also sort it this way

```
for i1, e1 in enumerate(a):
   for i2, e2 in enumerate(a):
      if e2 > e1:
         e1 = a[i2]
         a[i2] = a[i1]
         a[i1] = e1
```